# A Visual basic Web Control for Automation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, web, browser, webbrowser-control

I am working on a web browser in visual basic.I need to know if the *default*  **webcontrol** in *Visual Basic* is enough for the following.

I have the following inputs:

```
 1. User Agent="Mozilla blah blah"
 2. Javascript to be injected ="<script>doc.get['but'].click</script>"
 3. Url="http://foo.com"
```

The automation process is as follows.Use "**User Agent**" and Go to "**Url**", once page loads inject "**Javascript to be injected**" {This causes a button to be clicked:similar to using the *console* on other browsers}.

If the default webcontrol can't work with the mentioned inputs I would appreciate for suggestions regarding webcontrol libraries  that can do the above. And if the above can be done I would love to see some examples of the code.